# How much does the ferry between Rostock and Gedser cost?

Tags: germany, ferries, denmark

I am planning to visit Copenhagen for a couple of days. I will be travelling, by car, from Berlin, with 2 other friends. The quickest route is shown by taking the Rostock - Gedser ferry. I googled the cost of ferry and Scandlines says it costs 100€ for the crossing.

Is the ferry really that expensive?

Answer (score 5):

€100 sounds reasonable for a vehicle and 3 passengers. It is a 1 hour 45 minute crossing.

Did you get your price from [Scandlines](https://www.scandlines.com/tickets-und-tarife/tickets-and-prices/rostock-gedser.aspx) ?

Comment: I looked up the prices again. Thank you for the information.

Answer (score 3):

Let me say that I am *not* an experienced traveller on this route, however as far as I can tell you can get significant discounts to around €33 if you book early and join the SMILE customer loyalty program for free.

Additionally there is a route through Puttgarden -> Rodbyhavn which takes 17 minutes longer, however is around 30 euros cheaper if you book late. Same price if you book early though.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the Puttgarden-Rödby-Route. The Autobahn from Berlin to there is for the most part quite good. The ferry goes hourly and, as the trip is not so far, it is cheaper.

Also you´ll drive trough Fehmarn, which is quite a nice island in the Baltic sea of it´s own.

Edit: You can get a quote for your trip here (both routes):
https://www.scandlines.de/tickets-und-tarife/tickets-und-preise/rostock-gedser.aspx

Prices are for one vehicle <6meter length and up to 9 passengers.